# Why are the questions about Kaa basically not being answered?

Tags: kaa

I am not sure if this is a genuine question but I will try anyway.

The Kaa platform promises an open source IoT middle-ware apparently backed by a relatively large company. They [suggest](https://www.kaaproject.org/getting-started/) StackOverflow as the forum and place to ask about it, but for a few months basically no questions have been answered. Their older [forum](https://www.kaaproject.org/forum/), also sounds kind of abandoned.

Does anyone have any idea why?

If not I would like to use this question/post to raise some awareness, discussion among enthusiasts, and hopefully hear the developers' voices.

I believe in an open source project it is always important to have some feeling about the state of the project, and the community behind it (which, as the company states on their website: should be vibrant) before committing some development/testing time. Kaa sounds as a great alternative for IoT projects. I would like to hear some of the opinions from other developers who are using Kaa about this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: My friend, this is a genuine question for KAA forum. i am also felling/facing the same issues just like you. seems like it is not an open source project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pepgma, Mayur Patel,

Andrew Kokhanovskyi here, CTO at Kaa. First of all, please let me apologize for the lack of responses in public forums that you have experienced in the last few months. As you may know from our recent webinars, posts, etc., we are now working hard on the next version of the Kaa platform: codename "Banana Beach". It is because of the push to get the significantly improved version of Kaa to the early adopters that our engineering team has been having difficulties supporting all of the community requests lately.

Having said that, we truly appreciate your support of the Kaa open-source platform. As a token of gratitude, we would like to offer an invitation code: "AA-ADOPTER5" that you can use to register for the early access to Kaa BB here:

https://www.kaaproject.org/apply-for-early-access-to-kaa-1-0-banana-beach/

On our end, we will make sure that you will have a chance to be among the first ones to experience the new version of the Kaa platform.

--Andrew and the Kaa team

Comment: Thanks to step up and come forward,
 Andrew

Comment: Thumb up, thanks for answering. I am sure it is worth it